# Protect a string in Nancy app

Tags: .net, encryption, nancy, gist

I want to use the [Nancy Cryptography helpers](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-cryptography-helpers) to protect a string in a module.
But I can't seem to work out how to use them.

Can anyone point me to an example?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I worked it out:

```
using Nancy.Cryptography

var ec = CryptographyConfiguration.Default;
var enCryptedString = ec.EncryptionProvider.Encrypt("SomeString");
```

However, I can't see how to use a key or passphrase. Can anyone show me how it's done?

Answer (score 1):

The default is using `RandomNumberGenerator.Create();` so to control the keys you will need to provide your own implementation of `IKeyGenerator` & `IEncryptionProvider` interfaces